# Using Disqus SSO and ionic or Cordova

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, single-sign-on, disqus

I am trying to use the Disqus commenting system within my ionic app.

In tests users are complaining that they have to login to Disqus to leave comments. I would like to use Single Sign On to get around this problem.

Disqus has Single Sign On available for websites that use Disqus but I have not been able to find any documentation showing how this can be done within an ionic or Cordova app.